# jquery show hide div for multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a script that works when i click all 3 checkboxes it shows/hides 2 different divs.

```
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="chk2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="chk3" type="checkbox" />

var chkBoxes = $('#chk1,#chk2,#chk3');

      chkBoxes .change(function(){

      if (chkBoxes.filter(':checked').length == chkBoxes.length){
        $('#checked2').show();
        $('#checked1').hide();
      }else{
        $('#checked2').hide();
        $('#checked1').show();
      }
    });
```

Does anyone know how to modify this so i can disable the checkboxes as follows:

```
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
<input id="chk2" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
<input id="chk3" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
```

and have a link for each checkbox to do the change function and tick the checkbox. 
I'm using:

```
<a href="" onClick="document.checklist.chk1.value=1;">Link</a>
<a href="" onClick="document.checklist.chk2.value=1;">Link</a>
<a href="" onClick="document.checklist.chk3.value=1;">Link</a>
```

the above seems to work fine for checking the checkbox, but it does not invoke the jquery change function.

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aye. you need to fire off the checked event on the checkbox.. ill see if i can't manage to produce a jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/F7q4Y/

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#chk1').trigger('click');">Link1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="$('#chk2').trigger('click');">Link2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="$('#chk3').trigger('click');">Link3</a>
```

Comment: only problem im facing now is the disabled checkbox, everything else works. When the checkbox gets disabled it stops the onclick trigger that checks it. i tried Pehmolelu's answer below but that also did the same

Comment: @Matthew Brennand When element is disabled, events are also disabled.

Comment: @Pehmolelu  so is there no way round this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(selector).prop('disabled',true);` to do the disabled thing.

For clicking the links you could give a class for the link which refers to checkbox id:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#'+this.className).prop('checked',true);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: when i disable the checbox it stops the check trigger from the link

Answer (score 0):

First off I would add "return false" to the end of the onClick method.

Then instead of using pure javascript i would invoke the value change through jQuery.
If that doesn't work then try firing the event manually

```
$("#chk1").trigger("change");
```

Although if you are using links to check the checkboxes, why bother having the change event on the checkbox? Just put it on the links onClick method.

Something like

```
<a href=#" onClick="return checkAndToggleDiv($('chk1'));">Link</a>

checkAndToggleDiv(chk){
   chk.prop('checked',true);
   //do anything else you need, you can even use chk.prop('checked') 
   //to get the current value of checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to handle your `<a/>` click.

```
$("a[rel]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var chk = $("#" + $(this).attr("rel"))[0];
    chk.checked = !chk.checked;
    chkBoxes.change();
});
```

With the following markup:

```
<a href="" rel="chk1">Link 1</a>
<a href="" rel="chk2">Link 2</a>
<a href="" rel="chk3">Link 3</a>
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/KMawm/1/)**

Comment: :thanks for the reply mark i used the onclick="$('#chk1').trigger('click'); suggested by netbrain. but your jsfiddle example worked great.